# Python voice assistant that acts on trigger phrases

Tags: python, natural-language-processing

I made a Python voice assistant. It takes the user's voice input and there are multiple if-else statements that specify a condition and if it satisfies that condition it executes a specific function. How I can implement if-else statements in a more efficient way?

```
async def main():
    
    def there_exists(terms):
        for term in terms:
            if term in response or SequenceMatcher(None, response, term).ratio() > 0.85:
                return True

    while True:
        print("Listening..")
        response = takeCommand()

        if there_exists(["close current tab", 'close tab']):
            keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+w') 

        elif there_exists(['goodbye', 'bye', 'see you later', 'ok bye']):
            speak("Nice talking with you!")
            sys.exit(0)
        
        elif there_exists(['open google', 'open new tab in google', 'new tab in google']):
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
            speak("Google chrome is open now")
            time.sleep(5)

        elif there_exists(['open gmail', 'gmail']):
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")
            speak("Gmail is open now")
            time.sleep(5)

        elif 'open youtube' in response:
            openYoutube()

        elif there_exists(['whats the day today', 'what day is it today', 'day']):
            speak(f'Today is {getDay()}')

        elif there_exists(['battery percentage', 'what is the battery like right now', 'tell me the battery percentage']):
            speak("Current battery percentage is at" + str(percent) + "percent")

        elif there_exists(['what is the current brightness', 'current brightness', 'what is the brightness like right now']):
            speak(str(sbc.get_brightness()) + "percent")

        elif there_exists(["current location", "location", "where am i", "where am I right now"]):
            location()

        elif there_exists(['increase volume', 'volume up']):
            for i in range(3):
                pyautogui.press('volumeup')
            speak("Increase volume by 10 percent")

        elif there_exists(['decrease volume', 'volume down']):
            for i in range(3):
                pyautogui.press('volumedown')
            speak("Decreased volume by 10 percent")

        elif there_exists(["play"]):
            search_term = response.replace("play", '')
            kit.playonyt(search_term)
            speak(f"Playing {search_term}")

        elif there_exists(["on youtube"]):
            search_term = response.replace("on youtube", '')
            url = f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={search_term}"
            webbrowser.get().open(url)
            speak(f'Here is what I found for {search_term} on youtube')

        elif there_exists(["price of", "what is the price of", "tell me the price of"]):
            engine.setProperty("rate", 150)
            search_term = response.lower().split(" of ")[-1].strip()
            stock = getStock(search_term)
            speak(stock)
            print(stock)
            engine.setProperty("rate", 175)

        elif there_exists(['take a note', 'note', 'note this down', 'remember this', 'take this down']):
            speak("What do you want me to note down?")
            response = takeCommand()
            note(response)
            speak("I have made a note of that")

        elif there_exists(['tell me a joke', 'not funny', 'make me laugh', 'joke', 'tell me another joke']):
            joke = (pyjokes.get_joke())
            speak(joke)
            print(joke)

        elif there_exists(["search for"]) and 'youtube' not in response:
            search_term = response.split("for")[-1]
            url = f"https://google.com/search?q={search_term}"
            webbrowser.get().open(url)
            speak(f'Here is what I found for {search_term} on google')

        elif there_exists(['what is the time now', 'what time is it', 'time']):
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
            speak(f"the time is {strTime}")

        elif 'search' in response:
            response = response.replace("search", "")
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(response)
            time.sleep(5)

        elif there_exists(['sign out', 'log off']):
            speak(
                "Your pc will log off in 10 sec make sure you exit from all applications")
            subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/l"])

        elif there_exists(['shutdown the pc', 'shutdown', 'shutdown the laptop']):
            speak("Shutting down your pc, make sure you exit from all applications")
            subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])

        elif there_exists(['restart', 'restart the pc', 'restart the laptop']):
            speak("Restarting your pc, make sure you exit from all applications")
            subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/r"])

        elif there_exists(['what is the weather like right now', 'current temperature', 'climate']):
            weather = getWeather()
            speak(weather)
            print(weather)

        elif there_exists(['increase brightness', 'the brightness is low']):
            if sbc.get_brightness() == 100:
                speak("Brightness is already at max")
            else:
                brightness = sbc.set_brightness(current_brightness + 10)
                speak(f"Increased brightness by 10 percent")

        elif there_exists(
                ['decrease brightness', 'dim', 'dim the laptop', 'dim the screen', 'the screen is too bright']):
            sbc.set_brightness(current_brightness - 10)
            speak(f"Decreased brightness by 10 percent")

        elif there_exists(['take a screenshot', 'screenshot', 'capture the screen', 'take a photo of this']):
            image = pyscreenshot.grab()
            speak("Should I open the image?")
            response = takeCommand()
            if there_exists(['yes', 'show', 'show the screenshot']):
                image.show()
            else:
                speak("Ok")

        elif there_exists(['what is the weather in']):
            search_term = response.replace("what is the weather in", '')
            weather = getWeatherLocation(search_term)
            speak(weather)
            print(weather)

        elif there_exists(['what', 'who', 'why', 'where', 'when', 'which']):
            ans = getQuickAnswers(response)
            speak(ans)
            print(ans)

        elif there_exists(['send a message to']):
            search_term = response.replace('send a message to', '').replace(' ', '')
            await Methods().sendUserMessage(search_term)

asyncio.run(main())
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Please correct and verify the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dict with the expected input as keys and the actions as values.

```py
@dataclass
class ActionInput(Hashable):
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return str(self.value).__hash__()

    value: list[str]


actions = {
    ActionInput(["close current tab", 'close tab']): (lambda: print('ctrl+w')),
    # ...
}
```

and then loop over them:

```py
for key in actions:
    if there_exists(key.value):
        actions[key]()
```

Comment: I got this error: `NameError: name 'Hashable' is not defined. Did you mean: 'callable'?`

Comment: You can either `from typing import Hashable` to get type hints or remove the class inherit.